# Create an ADODB object

Tags: excel, vba

Running MS Office 2010 on Windows 7 Professional.

I'm trying to create a new ADODB object in my VBA project.  I've set a reference to the MS ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library, but that only seems to give me the ADOR object. I also tried Recordset 6.0, with the same results.  The reference is pointing to msador28.tlb, which probably explains the ADOR object.  So my question is, how do I update the reference so I can access the ADODB object?

Comment: There should also be a reference for `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library`.  You don't see it?

Comment: You need `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library`. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic?view=sql-server-ver15) at doc.Microsoft.com.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Yes, that did it.  I misread an example I was following, and referenced the wrong library.  My excuse - this is a new area for me.  Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thanks for your input, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to create an object via late binding? This may prevent the need for the library reference.

Example:

```
Dim rst As Object: Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```